# How to update composable UI fields asynchronously

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to achieve such flow.
I have viewmodel class with StateFlow variables.
I have associated @Composable fields with ViewModel variables.
In ComponentActivity by setcontent I want to run a function which will get data and set it to ViewModel but I need to show @Composable view which asynchronously will fill the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but the general way to go is the following:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
            // If you use dependency injection with hilt use this instead:
            // val viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()

            val data by viewModel.stateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

            Text(data)

        }
    }
}
```

You can convert the `StateFlow` from the view model to a compose `State`
object by using `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`. That's an extension function located in this artifact:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.0")
```

It will make sure that the flow is only collected when the composable is actually visible on screen (otherwise the value wouldn't be needed).

Using the `by` keyword above delegates the `value` of the state object to the data variable, so data then always contains the most current `value` of the `StateFlow`.
Assuming the flow contains a `String`, the data variable will also be of type `String`.
To display that string in the UI you can simply use the `Text` composable as shown above.

The UI will now always show the *current* value of the `StateFlow`. When the flow is updated anywhere in your app, the UI will automatically detect that and update the `Text` composable accordingly, there is nothing else for you to do to trigger an update of the UI.

That is, in fact, the huge benefit of Compose compared to other UI frameworks: You just define the values that should be displayed as `State` objects and Compose will make sure it always shows the current value by updating only those parts of the UI that used the state objects that were changed.